# MySQL creating a relationship between tables

Tags: mysql, relationship

If I have two tables:

```
    *******awards
    ----------------------
    aid | position | name
    ----------------------
     1      1        best game
     2      2        reached 100 points
     3      3        reached 300 points
     ................
     1000   800      logged_3_days_in_a_row

    *******users
    ----------------------
    uid | name
    ----------------------
     1    Niki
     2    Lulu33
     3    BadGirl
     .......
     1001 Zelda2012
```

What is the best way to make a relation between the awards table and the users? Of course I could create a `user_has_awards` table but I'm not sure if that's the best way (if there are 1000 or more awards and 1000 users) to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of relationship you want to establish. From your question I think you mean a many-to-many relationship (i.e. the same award can be given to many users and a user can have many awards). The best way to model this is indeed a third table which manages the relations between users and their awards.

See for instance this site explaining the design pattern: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

PS. you should start accepting some of the answers to your questions to encourage people to answer your questions.

Comment: .. and adding foreign keys to it will improve performance and data integrity